# ASP.NET RESTful Web Service

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services

I've been reading a lot about web services and I've come across the case where one could be very useful.
I've been thinking of implementing it with WCF but the host will be ASP.NET in a shared hosting environment with medium trust so from what I've read WCF doesn't seem like an option.
Also, I'm thinking of a RESTful web service and SOAP doesn't really interest me.
Is there any good resource explaining (to somebody who's not dealt with web services before but already has a good amount of experience with .NET) how to do something like what I'm after?
As a sidenote, the version of .NET that I intend to target is 3.5 (SP1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF works just fine with ASP.NET. It's a perfectly valid option. Of course, WCF and REST don't go hand-in-hand by default... [you'll need an extra library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx).

> *Thanks, could you please also link me
>   to some information about hosting WCF
>   services in ASP.NET?* – emaster70

[Sure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, could you please also link me to some information about hosting WCF services in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

Excellent screencasts on all things WCF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the early partial trust issues with WCF are pretty much history now. If your host is running .NET 3.5 SP1 then you shouldn't encounter any issues.

Here's an old article from one of the WCF team about what they had to do to have a better WCF story under partial trust:

[Partial Trust support for WCF in Orcas](http://hyperthink.net/blog/partial-trust-support-for-wcf-in-orcas/)